# Boot from usb attached to usb hub

Tags: linux, bootable-media, usb-hub

Is it possible to boot into a Linux live installation media from a usb stick attached to a usb hub?

Will it work if the usb hub is connected to a usb 2.0 port

The pc I am using only has 1 working usb 2.0 port.

Comment: Yes, probably. It all depends on the hardware though. Some crappy USB hubs may not be good to anything else than mice and keyboards.

Comment: You can try it and find out. If it does *not* work, in most cases you can boot from the USB, then unplug it, and plug the hub in.

Comment: you can contribute to community by replying to the comments, providing your feedback to the answers or even by answering your own question in case if existing answer are not relevant